# Generic method, generic type unknow

Tags: java, generics

I have many bean i would like to convert to Dto

In every class, i do something like

```
private List<AddressDto> convertsToDto(List<Address> addresses) {

    List<AddressDto> addressesDto = new ArrayList<>();
    addresses.stream().map((address) -> convertToDto(address)).forEachOrdered((addressDto) -> {
        addressesDto.add(addressDto);
    });
    return addressesDto;

}
```

convertToDto would be in every class.... but for convertsToDto i will put in t a abstract class where every class will extends it and put a generic convertsToDto method with generic type

```
public abstract class BaseService {
    public List<T> convertsToDto(List<R> beans) {

        List<T> listDto = new ArrayList<>();
        beans.stream().map((bean) -> convertToDto(bean)).forEachOrdered((dto) -> {
            listDto.add(dto);
        });
        return listDto;
    }
}
```

I always get `T` and `R` is unknown... seem to miss something.

Comment: Maybe add T and R as type parameters to the function? aka "public <T, R> List<T> conversToDto(List<R> beans)"

Comment: Generics are erased at compile time. At runtime it is always a List of Object. You should pass the type as parameter.

Comment: Why do need to use generics? why you don't just use your base abstract classes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Start with adding `T` and `R` type parameters to your generic method. However, this will not do the trick, because `convertToDto(bean)` would remain undefined.

You have several options here:

- You could define bean interface to produce its DTO, or
- You could pass a bean-to-DTO function object.

Here is the first approach:

```
interface Bean<T> {
    T convertToDto();
}
public abstract class BaseService {
    public <T,R extends Bean<T>> List<T> convertsToDto(List<R> beans) {
        return beans.stream().map((b) -> b.convertToDto()).collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
    ... // Additional methods
}
```

Here is the second approach:

```
public abstract class BaseService {
    public <T,R> List<R> convertsToDto(List<T> beans, Function<T,R> convert) {
        return beans.stream().map((b) -> convert.apply(b)).collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
}
```

Comment: from the first option, in my class, when i try to call method convertsToDto     i get: method convertsToDto in class BaseService cannot be applied to given types;
  required: List<R>
  found: List<Address>
  reason: inference variable R has incompatible bounds
    equality constraints: Address
    upper bounds: Bean<T,R>
  where R,T are type-variables:
    R extends Bean<T,R> declared in method <T,R>convertsToDto(List<R>)
    T extends Object declared in method <T,R>convertsToDto(List<R>)

Comment: @roberttrudel It looks like your `Bean` interface is different - it takes two parameters, not one. First solution uses one parameter, `T`, which corresponds to the target DTO type. In other words, if your target DTO for `Address` is `AddressDto`, then `Address` must `implement Bean<AddressDto>`.

Comment: I think should have something like  public T convertToDto(R r); because input parameter should be different from output

Comment: second approach seem  easier to implement

Comment: @roberttrudel Second approach also lets you use this code when you have no access to your bean class, and cannot "pin" a new interface on them. However, it requires a lambda or a converter function object each time you invoke `convertToDtos`.

Comment: @roberttrudel `Bean<T>` interface has only one type parameter, that of its target DTO, because its `convertToDto` method has no parameters other than the implicit `this` parameter, i.e. `b` in `b.convertToDto()`

Answer (score 1):

Your BaseService class does not define these generic types.

```
Try 
public abstract class BaseService<T, R> {
...
}

public class AddressService extends BaseService<AddressDto, Address> {
...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can have a generic interface like `Dto<T>` for this to work.

And you will be able to have your generic convertion method to look like this:

```
public <T extends Dto<R>> List<T> convertsToDto(List<R> beans) {
}
```

Your `Dto` objects will be implementing the interface mapping them to the base object.